# SELinux does not log denial

Tags: selinux, linux-audit

SELinux does not allow `auditd` to start the process (named `myplagin`) and does not log the reason in the `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. The only mention of the denial I found in the `/var/log/messages`: `Centos8 auditd[3119]: Unable to stat /home/cust/myplagin (Permission denied)`, but I would like to see an audit.log-style denial (`type=AVC msg=audit(1705309402.866:1150): avc:  denied`) to understand what new rules need to be added to the policy.

If you switch SELinux to the Permissive mode, myplagin starts without problems

Answer (score 0):

There are some denials that don't output anything in the audit log file.

To see these denials, you can temporarily disable "dontaudit" rules with:

```bash
semodule -DB
```

And enable them again once you finished to diagnose:

```bash
semodule -B
```

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-possible_causes_of_silent_denials)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: It means you don't have more logs in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`? You have nothing with `audit2allow -a` either?

Comment: I started getting more denied logs in `audit.log` and `messages.log` after this command, but still no denied log about `myplagin`

Still, there is only a single mention of `Unable to stat` in `messages.log` and that’s it